# Could not parse XML document - Postgres query to get row count in tables

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have the following script to find the number of rows for every table in postgres schema.

```
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       (xpath('/row/x/text()', xml_cnt))[1]::text::int  as row_count
from (
  select table_name, table_schema,
         query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as x from %I.%I having count(*) =0 ', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') as xml_cnt
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_schema = 'my_schema' 
   
) k
```

However, it throws the following error.

ERROR:  could not parse XML document
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not parse XML document
SQL state: 2200M

I want to find all tables with row count equal to zero.

The above script works when 'having(*) =0' is not used in the query but it gives all tables with their row counts.

```
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       (xpath('/row/x/text()', xml_cnt))[1]::text::int  as row_count
from (
  select table_name, table_schema,
         query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as x from %I.%I ', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') as xml_cnt
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_schema = 'my_schema' 
   
) k
```

Is there a way to modify the query and get the behavior I want?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the tags for the many different (and unsupported) Postgres versions. If you need a version specific solution, add one tag for that version.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `SELECT nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
FROM pg_class 
JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = pg_class.relnamespace)
WHERE 
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' 
ORDER BY reltuples DESC;` I'm not sure why you want to use xml for this purpose

Comment: @JimJones I used the script you posted with the above modification. Its really great that it can give the numbers for each schema too. But its giving the estimated row count. Not the exact count.

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause makes that you get an empty result for empty tables. This leads to an empty XML document, which causes the error.